# Python function takes N positional parameters but M were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, parameters

I am trying to call a function in the following manner:

```
for TestCase in sys.argv[1:]:
    TestTree = ET.parse(TestCase)
    Root = TestTree.getroot()
    inputFile = Root[0].text
    start_server(inputFile)

def start_server (inputFile):
     server_process = Process(target=HTTPServer.initServer, args=(inputFile))
     server_process.start()

def initServer(self,inputFile):
    print(inputFile)
```

However, on executing these lines, I get a TraceBack with the following error:

```
TypeError: initServer() takes 2 positional arguments but 182 were given
```

Here, inputFile is a simple HTML Webpage.
Where am I going wrong and sending 182 arguments?

Comment: did you copy-paste this? it sounds like it is passed `*inputFile` or something

Comment: I copy-pasted this from my own code. It wasn't copied from anywhere else though.

Comment: Oh. try passing `args=(inputFile, )`

Comment: Elazar: That worked after removing self as the first argument in initServer(). 
Though could you please explain why this happens? Also, if you write that as an answer, I could accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/multiprocessing.html):

> `args` is the argument tuple for the target invocation

So it must be a tuple. You've provided `(inputFile)` - equivalent to simple `inputFile`. This is the actual file, which is iterable. `Process` implementation is probably doing `target(*args)`, which unpacks the file to its lines.

You should pass `args=(inputFile, )`, which is a tuple containing a single object. so `*args` becomes `inputFile`, as expected.